# Consecutive units for next 4 weeks based record date against each product

Tags: sql

/***********Input data************/

```
Product# Date        Units
P1  9/1/2019    10
P1  9/04/2019   20
P2  9/27/2019   30
```

I need to assign the above Product Units for the next 4 weeks like below condition,

1. For the current week of Product, their units should be 0.
2. and next 4 week based on the date given in the above sample data by-product, it should be the same unit.

   - for eg, P1 product- week1 start date is 09/02/2019(week start date is Monday) units will be 0, for next 4 weeks like 09/09,09/16,09/23,09/30 the units count will be 10 for product P1.

/***********Output data************/

```
Product#  Date        Weeks  start  Units
P1  9/1/2019    9/2/2019    0
P1  9/1/2019    9/9/2019    10
P1  9/1/2019    9/16/2019   10
P1  9/1/2019    9/23/2019   10
P1  9/1/2019    09/30/019   10
P1  9/4/2019    9/2/2019    0
P1  9/4/2019    9/9/2019    20
P1  9/4/2019    9/16/2019   20
P1  9/4/2019    9/23/2019   20
P1  9/4/2019    09/30/019   20
P2  9/27/2019   9/23/2019   0
P2  9/27/2019   09/30/019   30
P2  9/27/2019   10/7/2019   30
P2  9/27/2019   10/14/2019  30
P2  9/27/2019   10/21/2019  30
```

/************************Input************************/

```
Product Id  Date    Units
P1  9/1/2019    10
P1  9/15/2019   20
P2  9/23/2019   30
```

/************************Output ************************/

```
Product#    Date    Weeks  start    Units
P1  9/1/2019    9/2/2019    0
P1  9/1/2019    9/9/2019    10
P1  9/1/2019    9/16/2019   10
P1  9/1/2019    9/23/2019   10
P1  9/1/2019    09/30/019   10
P1  9/4/2019    9/2/2019    0
P1  9/4/2019    9/9/2019    20
P1  9/4/2019    9/16/2019   20
P1  9/4/2019    9/23/2019   20
P1  9/4/2019    09/30/019   20
P2  9/27/2019   9/23/2019   0
P2  9/27/2019   09/30/019   30
P2  9/27/2019   10/7/2019   30
P2  9/27/2019   10/14/2019  30
P2  9/27/2019   10/21/2019  30
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want Monday as the first day of week.  datefirst does that.
Since you have P1 listed multiple times, the data is not normalized and it is not easy to sort.  I have taken the data and added a sortorder row for sorting.  It's basically a sorted unique ID.

After that, calculate the first day of the week and then union it with each of the next 4 weeks.

```
set datefirst 1

declare @Input table (Product varchar(2), Product_Date date, Units int)

insert into @Input
   values('P1','2019-09-01',10),
         ('P1','2019-09-04',20),
         ('P2','2019-09-27',30)

declare @Input_Normalized table
   (Product varchar(2), Product_Date date, Units int, SortOrder int)

insert into @Input_Normalized
select *, row_number() over (order by Product, Product_Date, Units) SortOrder
from @Input

select *
from (
   select Product, Product_Date,
      DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Product_Date), Product_Date) Week_Start,
      0 Units, SortOrder
   from @Input_Normalized
) a
union all
(
   select Product, Product_Date,
      DATEADD(DAY, 8 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Product_Date), Product_Date) Week_Start,
      Units, SortOrder
   from @Input_Normalized
)
union all
(
   select Product, Product_Date,
      DATEADD(DAY, 15 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Product_Date), Product_Date) Week_Start,
      Units, SortOrder
   from @Input_Normalized
)
union all
(
   select Product, Product_Date,
      DATEADD(DAY, 22 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Product_Date), Product_Date) Week_Start,
      Units, SortOrder
   from @Input_Normalized
)
union all
(
   select Product, Product_Date,
      DATEADD(DAY, 29 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Product_Date), Product_Date) Week_Start,
      Units, SortOrder
   from @Input_Normalized
)
order by SortOrder, Product, Week_Start
```

Note this does not produce the same output that you have.  This is because 9/1/2019 is not in the week beginning on 9/2/2019.  This seems like an error in what you expect for output.  If 9/1/2019 should indeed be in the week beginning on 9/2/2019, you'll have to explain how/why.